# How to open wubi's .disk files under windows?

Tags: windows, wubi, disk

Wubi has created one big file with whole ubuntu installation **root.disk** - there are some files I have left on my linux partition that I would like to access from windows partition,

Is there any way to mount/open this file under windows?

P.S. I think its **ubuntu question**, because **Wubi is a windows compatible linux**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **[Explore2fs](http://www.chrysocome.net/explore2fs)** is a GUI explorer tool for accessing ext2 and ext3 filesystems.
- It runs under all versions of Windows and can read almost any ext2 and ext3 filesystem.
- For more information look at this **[link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How%20can%20I%20access%20the%20Wubi%20files%20from%20Windows?)**.

Answer (score 6):

Explore2fs did not work for me (don't know why)

An alternative that definitely works is ext2explore, which can be downloaded from the following website

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/files/

Download it and browse for the .disk file where you installed ubuntu. It worked for me, even in kubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Use 7zip file manager. Right click on the .disk file in Windows and click open (or "open with" if there is an option) and click browse. Then go to Program files and 7zip. Then choose 7zip.exe

Answer (score -1):

This post described how to mount .disk file but you has to use live CD or USB.
[How-to: Recover files from Wubi install with LiveCD](http://neosmart.net/forums/showthread.php?t=5004)

Comment: The question is how to open the files under windows, not from a live CD. Also you should include the relevant information in your answer, rather than just posting a link (that could become stale)

Comment: @bcbc:thats right, but everyone knows that all those windows extn drivers suck and may ruin the file-system.

Comment: @Behrooz everyone knows? Well, not me, I guess. Please post the relevant links so I can educate myself. Thanks

Comment: @bcbc example `http://www.ext2fsd.com/` quote :"The driver may crash your system and ruin your data unexpectedly".

Comment: @Behrooz that's pretty *to the point*, but at the end of the day it's just a disclaimer. Next time you install any Windows software, pay attention to the EULA and it says pretty much the same thing, just less bluntly. I've been recommending (and using) `Ext2Read` and never had any reports of crashes or data loss. Any real life examples?

Comment: @bcbc:my disks?nah.I don't use windows. But the disclaimer/EULA seamed so different from what i have seen before.Maybe they just wanted to make sure nobody sues them.