# Use of 30GB installation

Tags: 12.04, wubi

Please tell me the Difference between 18 and 30 GB wubi installation.
Do I get all packages installed in 30gb wubi installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Installation size" options lets you decide the amount of space you want to "give up" for WUBI. That is the space wubi's Ubuntu install is able to use. Wubi creates a disk image (loopmounted device) on your host system in/on which Ubuntu is installed. This can be compared to a kind of "safe partition" on your system.

See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/139018/190009) for details

Comment: Can you even please tell me about the wine software.... I faced many problems in installing it and do i need to install packages for it???

Comment: use this [link](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu)

Comment: Ok... Now What if I have the setup of visual studio 2008 ... How should i install it in ubuntu using wine?

Comment: You can ask it as separate question indeed. But will give your ans in 5min kind of busy now

Comment: Right click on the exe file and select properties. Then check "Allow executing as program" in the Permissions tab. Try it works

Comment: Thanks Aatish for the answer. Actually I am new to this forum. So me heavily confused :)

Comment: You want to upvote the answer if it helps