# How can I recover files inside a Wubi install before re-installing Ubuntu?

Tags: wubi, startup, boot-failure

I failed to inter Ubuntu with this error

```
GNU GRUB VERSION 1.99-21........etc
```

I spoke with technical support at www.ubuntu.com he was really nice and he served me will I thank him very much.... but I didn't like his last solution

> From the helpfulpost of Boot-info I can see that the partition where
>       you installed Ubuntu (wubi /dev/sda1) is corrupted.
>       The boot-repair tool attempted to repair thatwith the fsck command but
>       it wasn't possible. (failed).
>       I have not further suggestion but to remove Ubuntu installation from
>       within windows (Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Feautures >
>       Uninstall) and then install it again.
>       Of course you will lose your datafrom Ubuntu.
>       Thanks

can you give me other solution or tool so I can save my personal files !!!!!
this is my "boot repair" report
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1281522/

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21264/how-to-open-wubis-disk-files-under-windows might help save your files before needing to re-install Ubuntu. Don't worry unless something went horribly wrong your files should still be safe and sound inside the disk files.

Comment: Your root.disk is missing... which indicates NTFS corruption, not ext4 corruption. So refer to this: http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.ca/2011/08/missing-rootdisk.html

Answer (score 2):

When you try to boot a Wubi install and you end up at a `grub>` prompt, then most likely it's the result of corruption. Wubi installs Ubuntu on a large virtual partition that is a single file called the `root.disk` (if you install on a `FAT32` partition, other `.disk` files are created as well).

To confirm it you can run the `bootinfoscript` and you'll see something like:

```
sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe 
                       /ntldr /NTDETECT.COM /wubildr /ubuntu/winboot/wubildr 
                       /wubildr.mbr /ubuntu/winboot/wubildr.mbr 
                       /ubuntu/disks/swap.disk
```

You can see it lists `/ubuntu/disks/swap.disk`, but it's also supposed to show `/ubuntu/disks/root.disk`.

If this happens, the first thing to do is to boot Windows and run `chkdsk /f` or `chkdsk /r` (the latter also looks for damaged disk sectors). This will repair any `NTFS` file system corruption and sometimes fix the damaged `root.disk` file (but not always).

Here's how to do it from Windows 7. Go to `Computer`, right click on the "drive" you selected when you installed Wubi e.g. `C:\`, and select `Properties`, `Tools`, `Error-checking` `Check now`, and then `Start`:

[image]

If you installed Ubuntu on the `C:\` "drive", then you have to reboot Windows to let `chkdsk` complete. Make sure you don't hit any key at bootup or it will cancel the scan.

Now comes the tricky part. Sometimes Windows will remove the repaired file to a hidden folder called `\found.000` or `\found.001` (it increments). And in most cases the file name will be lost, so you'll see a file called `file0000.chk` inside there. In this case you want to look for a file that's about the size of the `root.disk` (at least `5GB` and up to `30GB`). You can move that back to `\ubuntu\disks\root.disk` and you should be good to go. If the entire `\ubuntu\disks` directory is repaired, then instead you might see a directory `\found.000\dir0000.chk` and inside that you may find `root.disk` and `swap.disk`. In this case, move the directory back, renaming it to `disks`.

Here is how to do it... hit the Windows key + R, type `cmd`, look above and right-click on `CMD.EXE`, and select `Run as administrator`. Then from the command like:

```
C:\>cd \found.000
C:\found.000>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is B4B7-99A8

 Directory of C:\found.000

19/07/2011  02:02 PM    15,000,000,000 file0000.chk
               1 File(s)              8 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  222,258,069,504 bytes free

C:\found.000>move file0000.chk \ubuntu\disks\root.disk
        1 file(s) moved.
```

or if the whole disks folder is recovered

```
C:\found.000>move dir0000.chk \ubuntu\disks
        1 dir(s) moved.
```