# booting goes to grub

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my packard bell dots notebook about 10 days ago downloading wubi from the Ubuntu site. It has worked excellently since then (except flash player problem which no amount of adobe downloads fixes). today it won't boot : when I choose Ubuntu over Windows I get

```
GNU Grub Version 1.99-21 Ubuntu3.7  
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word TAB list possible      command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.  
grub>
```

so I press TAB and get

```
Possible commands are:
[ authenticate background-color background-image badram boot break clear cofigfile continue cutmem echo export extract-entries-configfile extract-entries-source initrd imsmod linux loadfront loopback is LSfont menuentry normal normal-exit probe return search search.file search.fs-lable search.fs-uuid set setparams shift source submenu terminal-input terminal-output test unset
grub>
```

I am not technical at all and feel overwhelmed. I would happily try to download Wubi again, but fear I will lose my excel and word worksheets.

Please could someone help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try `boot` when you get prompted for a command.

If that doesn't work then you can recover your files(excel etc.) from the .disk file, which can be found in the folder where you installed ubuntu.
See this answer [How to open wubi's .disk files under windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21264/how-to-open-wubis-disk-files-under-windows)

Comment: Thank you. I tried boot after grub and the following came up : "error : no loaded kernel"

Comment: I don't know much about grub commands but you can get your data back...

Comment: OK thank you I have rebooted via Windows and the system has reopened as new. I think that I have lost the other data, but thank you for all your timely advice. I do appreciate it