# Ubuntu does not appear in Grub Menu. Boot Repair Failed

Tags: boot, 13.04, dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

I have a Hard-Drive with Windows 7 and Ubuntu. Until a few days ago I was using Ubuntu 12.10 but after a lot of crashes errors and broken packages Ubuntu stopped booting at all.
With a live DVD I installed Ubuntu 13.04 without problems but after some updates that required a reboot the system booted directly to a black screen with the text "grub recovery >".

I ran boot repair and afterwards i was able to access Windows 7 but if I select Ubuntu the grub menu just shows "Windows recovery" and "Windows boot loader".

This is the link with the information from Boot Repair. *

Hopefully someone can help me, because I really have no clue on how to access the files from Ubuntu 13.04.  The Files from ubuntu 12.10 were available trough boot Repair as a mounted disk in a trial version of ubuntu, but the installation of 13.10 was not detected.

<sub>* - link to data summary is inactive and has been removed</sub>

Answer (score 0):

From the boot-repair log,it was clearly shown that you had installed ubuntu 13.04 via windows installer(wubi).

To get files from the wubi partition see [How to open wubi's .disk files under windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21264/how-to-open-wubis-disk-files-under-windows)