# How to mount root.disk file?

Tags: wubi

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my Windows 7 PC using wubi. The system does not boot and I'm trying to mount root.disk file in order to restart it from a Ubuntu live USB. But terminal shows me:

```
mount: Stale file handle
```

I have no idea what it means, nor how can I solve it. Any idea?

The commands that I used were:

```
sudo mkdir /media/win7ub
sudo mkdir /media/ubuntu1404
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda3 /media/win7ub
sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop /media/win7ub/ubuntu/disks.root.disk /media/ubuntu1404
```

I run WIndows 7 professional and my PC does not support UEFI. I installed WUBI 12.10

Comment: Wubi is no longer developed or supported: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14245/is-wubi-off-topic

Comment: *Steve Mena Navarro*: Please **[edit]** with details: What version of Windows are you running, and how was *it* installed? Wubi doesn't work with Windows's UEFI boot loader. If you're running Windows 8 or later, Wubi is only likely to work if you upgraded from a previous version of Windows; it *won't* work if Windows 8 or later was preinstalled by the manufacturer (such systems use UEFI). @MichaelBay 14.04 has Wubi; we support 14.04 until it is EoL. I've closed that meta question as a duplicate of a much higher voted one by the same OP. That question and those linked to it may interest you.

Comment: I've added the details that you recommend me.

Comment: Which `mount` command resulted in the error message in the question? The issue sounds a bit weird because there should be no way for file handles to turn stale when only local file systems are involved.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/21264/how-to-open-wubis-disk-files-under-windows and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105260/what-does-stale-file-handle-in-linux-means